# What does the "where" represent?

Tags: grammar

There is a sentence:

> Acute aortic dissection represents the only hypertensive emergency where rapid, aggressive blood pressure reduction is indicated.

Does the "where" on the former sentence represent for which or something else?

Comment: *in which*, similar to *the only situation where that happens is XYZ*

Comment: When quoting from a source, please provide links!

Comment: "Where" has "only hypertensive emergency" as antecedent.